# Node js adding new property to a array of objects when returning from mongoose collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating app using *nodejs*, *express*, *mongoose*. And `mongodb.user` is the mongoose schema model and I am trying to fetch user array of objects, that query is perfect and my problem is I want to add new property for each user. I have tried as follows. But it does not add to the collection.

```
exports.memberlist = function(req, res) {
        user.find({}).exec(function(err, collection) {
             collection.forEach(function(member){
             member.city  = 'Colombo';
             collection.push(member);
             });
        res.send(collection);
        });
};
```

Comment: you are pushing into the collection you are iterating through. Is it replacing the existing item?

Comment: there is no item called city in user collection . i want to add new item with value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Mongoose doesn't allow to add a property to an object extracted from MongoDB DB. To do so, you have two alternatives :

```
1/ before exec statement you add a lean() method : 
user.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, collection) {do whatever you want with collection}

2/ collection = collection.toObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

in Schema level create create virtual property

```
userSchema.virtual('city').get(function () {
  return 'Colombo';
});
```

in controller level

```
exports.memberlist = function(req, res,next)
{
  user.find({}).exec(function(err, users)
    {
if(!err)
{
res.json(200, users.toObject({virtual: true}));
}
else
{
next(err);
}

    });
};
```

Comment: thank u for your answer. but actually i want to set the city element by querying another collection within the loop.

Comment: you can use Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback); you can set in options multi:true it will update all the documents before doing any thins add to field to Schema

Comment: exports.memberlist = function(req, res)
{
  user.find({}).exec(function(err, collection)
    {
      collection.forEach(function(member)
        {
    subscriptions.find({member._id},'city', function(err, subscription){
  member.city = subscription.city;
           collection.push(member);

   });
          
     });
      res.send(collection);
    });
};here the subscription is another mongoose model and i want to get city from that specific user and
add it to the member object.

Comment: why you are using collection.push(member)

Comment: you trying to create new document

Comment: no i want to add that city element to the member object from querying another mongoose model.

Comment: you can change your code  like this member.city  = 'Colombo';
             member.save(function(err,result){ });

Comment: i dont want to add that property to the user collection. i want to send a json response with the city property.

Comment: userSchema.options.toObject.transform = function (doc, ret, options) {

    ret.city  = 'Colombo';
      
}; you can configure at schema level  check mongoose transform() documentation